# How to make 7zip behave like bzip (to zip a file and delete the original)?

Tags: 7zip

I like to use bzip to zip up files because it deletes the original and leaves the new file.

How can I use 7zip to zip up a file and delete the original after it is done zipping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `sudo apt-get install p7zip`
2. `p7zip <filename>` to compress it (it doesnt leave the original file)
3. `p7zip -d <filename>.7z` to decompress it

**Sample Run:**

```
~/Temp$ ls -ltrh
total 4.0K
-rwxrwxr-x 1 thefourtheye thefourtheye 851 Jun 18 20:22 TestIP.sh

~/Temp$ p7zip TestIP.sh 

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_IN,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)
Scanning

Creating archive TestIP.sh.7z

Compressing  TestIP.sh      

Everything is Ok

~/Temp$ ls -ltrh
total 4.0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thefourtheye thefourtheye 567 Jun 20 08:53 TestIP.sh.7z

~/Temp$ p7zip -d TestIP.sh.7z 

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_IN,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,2 CPUs)

Processing archive: TestIP.sh.7z

Extracting  TestIP.sh

Everything is Ok

Size:       851
Compressed: 567

~/Temp$ ls -ltrh
total 4.0K
-rwxrwxr-x 1 thefourtheye thefourtheye 851 Jun 18 20:22 TestIP.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

p7zip seems delete the archive after extracting it.

Use 7za instead. It comes with 'p7zip-full' package.

For example, :

$ apt-get install p7zip-full

$ 7za e abc.7z