# Do I need to install p7zip or p7zip-full on 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, 7zip, file-roller

I have just installed Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet (+restricted extras), and noticed that I didn't have to install `p7zip` or `p7zip-full` to work with .7z files.

As far as I can see it is `libarchive13` that is responsible for giving File Roller the ability to work with the 7z format, but is it still advisable to install `p7zip` or `p7zip-full`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep p7zip` terminal command there.

Comment: @Pilot6 Why? I don't have the package installed. They question goes on whether I should install it, or the already installed implementation is sufficient.

Comment: @Pilot6 If you must know, the output of that command is (as expected) empty.

Comment: I have not heard that file-roller could handle archives itself. It is just a wrapper. But if it works, why worry about that?

Comment: According to package description `libarchive13` has some limitations for 7z format.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, but what limitations? I am unable to find that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24105/discussion-between-beruic-and-pilot6).

Comment: p7zip-full installs an additional command line tool,  7za, which has more options than the p7zip command and does not remove the original file after completing an operation .  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/310397/how-to-make-7zip-behave-like-bzip-to-zip-a-file-and-delete-the-original

Answer (score 0):

simply use below command buddy:

```
sudo apt-get install dtrx
dtrx archive.tar.XX
```

Comment: what does the command do?

Comment: I agree with @Tim. `apt-cache search dtrx` tells me `dtrx - intelligently extract multiple archive types`